# Adding new field to TestReport object and using it in pytest_html_results_table_html hook

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I want to get information about exceptions raised during  test `call` phase and add them to report created with `pytest-html` plugin. So I created `hookwrapper` for `pytest_runtest_makereport`:

```
@hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(call):
    outcome = yield
    result = outcome.get_result()
    errors = getattr(result, "errors", [])
    if result.when == "call":
        if result.failed:
            if error := call.excinfo:
                errors.append(error.typename)
                result.errors = errors
        else:
            logger.info("PASSED")
```

To add this information to test report, I'm using:

```
def pytest_html_results_table_html(report, data):
    del data[:]
    if errors := getattr(report, "errors", []):
        data.append(html.div(", ".join(errors), class_="failed log"))
```

Unfortunately in `pytest_html_results_table_html` there is no errors field in report instance. If I add `result.errors = errors` to teardown phase, field appears in report object but it has empty list.
I know there is an `extra` field, but `pytest-html` adds it straight into report. I want to do something with those values before adding them.

So what I'm missing here? How to pass this value from `pytest_runtest_makereport` to `pytest_html_results_table_html`?

Example test class that I'm using:

```
from logging import getLogger

from pytest import fixture

logger = getLogger()


class TestVariousOutputs:
    @fixture()
    def setup(self):
        logger.info("Run setup")
        raise RuntimeError("Error raised during setup")

    @fixture()
    def teardown(self):
        logger.info("Run setup")
        yield
        logger.info("Run teardown")
        raise RuntimeError("Error raised during teardown")

    def test_pass(self):
        logger.info("Run test")
        assert True

    def test_fail(self):
        logger.info("Run test")
        assert False, "Assert False"

    def test_raise_error(self):
        logger.info("Run test")
        raise RuntimeError("Error raised during test run")

    def test_setup_raise_error(self, setup):
        logger.info("Run test")
        assert True

    def test_teardown_raise_error(self, teardown):
        logger.info("Run test")
        assert True

    def test_teardown_raise_error_and_test_fails(self, teardown):
        logger.info("Run test")
        assert False, "Assert False but teardown should also fail"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is how `pytest-html` is currently implemented: for each test case, it will take the `teardown` report and copy selected fields from the `call` and `setup` reports. Of course, custom fields are simply ignored (duh!). You thus have to intercept this post-processing of `pytest` reports and ensure your custom field is present on `teardown` report. Example to put into your `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)  # run our hookimpl before pytest-html does its own postprocessing
def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    html_report = getattr(session.config, "_html", None)
    for rep_setup, rep_call, rep_teardown in html_report.reports.values():
        # copy errors field from call report to teardown report
        rep_teardown.errors = getattr(rep_call, "errors", [])
```